# AVRO - Complex Records with Union Record type support

Tags: avro

I am trying to build an AVRO's complex record with Union data type supported member record type.

```
{
    "namespace": "proj.avro",
    "protocol": "app_messages",
    "doc" : "application messages",
    
    "types": [
        {
            "name": "record_request",
            "type" : "record", 
            "fields": 
            [
                {
                    "name" : "request_id", 
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "message_type",
                    "type" : int,
                },
                {
                    "name" : "users",
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "request_response",
            "type" : "record",
            "fields" :
            [
                {
                    "name" : "request_id",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "response_code",
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "response_count",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "reason_code",
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    
    "messages" :
    {
        "published_msgs" :
        {
            "doc" : "My Messages",
            "fields" :
            [
                {
                    "name" : "message_type",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "message_body",
                    "type" : 
                    [
                        "record_request", "request_response"
                    ]
                }
            ]
            
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error while trying to read this kind of schema.

I would like to know - is it possible to declare such AVRO schema - which has one of field which type is union of complex user defined message structure.

If its possible then could you please let me know what i am doing wrong or an example of such structure with union type field's type definition?

I want to use AVRO's dynamically schema usage - so specify this schema file run-time and parse the incoming buffer as "request"/"response".

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

It is possible define an union of complex types, the problem with your schema is that it is not defined at field level.  Your schema must looks like this to achieve the union of complex types

```
{
    "namespace": "proj.avro",
    "protocol": "app_messages",
    "doc" : "application messages",
    "name": "myRecord",
    "type" : "record",
    "fields": [
    {
    "name": "requestResponse",
    "type": [
        {
            "name": "record_request",
            "type" : "record", 
            "fields": 
            [
                {
                    "name" : "request_id", 
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "message_type",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "users",
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "request_response",
            "type" : "record",
            "fields" :
            [
                {
                    "name" : "request_id",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "response_code",
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "response_count",
                    "type" : "int"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "reason_code",
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to define schema as "types" instead of defining them inside message structure i.e. using "types" keyword. We would like to define them using "types" which will be easy from re-usability plus maintenance point of view. Specially when we add more structures/types.

Comment: it is not (at least i am not aware). I think you should try a different solution depending on your type of applications, have you tried schema registry ?