# Trying to create AVRO schema from a json

Tags: avro

This is my json, trying to create a write command in kafka

```
{
  "devId": "ABCABCABC",
  "msgId": 207,
  "addr": 13,
  "cmd": "write",
  "regs": [
    [
      "0x00AF",
      16,
      "H",
      1,
      50
    ]
  ]
}
```

so created a avro schema in many different types like

```
{
  "namespace": "aa.hivekafka.abc",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "d_write_cmd",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "devId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "msgId",
      "type": "long"
    },
         {
      "name": "addr",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "cmd",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "regs",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
              "type": "array",
              "items":"string"
            }
        }
        }  

  ]
}
```

in the above format if the regs  **[
"0x00AF",
"16",
"H",
"1",
"50"
]** given as string it works and not working with the mix of int and string, I tried many combinations any suggestion on this will be really appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031364/avro-complex-records-with-union-record-type-support

Comment: @K.Nicholas That's for records, not arrays

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. For example - assume you generated a Java class from this schema, then would you expect `Object[] regs` field? since it cannot be `String[]` or `int[]`. Ultimately, JSON/Kafka don't care about types, but Avro does... You could make an array of `record` types, that do have a union type, however, as the comment above mentions

Comment: thanks for the responses instead of avro we created as json schemas and it works